# iPhone Upgrade Program without adding line or upgrading?

Tags: iphone-upgrade-program

Is it possible to do the iPhone upgrade program without having to either upgrade an existing line or adding a new one?  Just doing it for monthly payments?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.  You're required to either upgrade an existing line or add a new line through the IUP.

You don't have to use your existing cellular carrier.  If you have, for example, AT&T and want to use T-Mobile for a specific iPhone purchase, you can do that.  However, you need to select a carrier for the iPhone (even though they're sold unlocked).

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired, but it seems like your 2nd paragraph somewhat contradicts your first?  I know I need to select a carrier, but I can't just select AT&T and then plug in my old SIM card after it arrives?  I want to get the new X, but not eligible for an upgrade without paying off the old first, but don't have the money to pay off the old until I actually sell it, but don't want to go a week without a phone.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is just an example of switching carriers when upgrading a line.  You can't select AT&T but not provide a line that's on AT&T during checkout.  This is to prevent you from doing exactly what you've described.